# PostgreSQL create table statement: auto insert id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 14. For tenant system, My script

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tenant;
CREATE TABLE tenant
(
    id               smallserial primary key,
    company_tax_code character varying(14),
    period           character varying(16), -- 2021070420220705
    created          timestamp with time zone
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS account_default;
CREATE TABLE account_default
(
    id               smallint,
    ref_type         smallint               not null,
    ref_type_name    character varying(256),
    voucher_type     smallint               not null,
    column_name      character varying(64)  not null,
    column_caption   character varying(128) not null,
    filter_condition character varying(1024),
    default_value    character varying(32),
    sort_order       smallint,
    created          timestamp with time zone,
    created_by       character varying(64),
    modified         timestamp with time zone,
    modified_by      character varying(64),
    tenant_id        smallint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, tenant_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_tenant FOREIGN KEY (tenant_id) REFERENCES tenant (id)
);
```

I am looking something like

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS account_default;
CREATE TABLE account_default
(
    id               smallint default value (max_value of account_default.id + 1 where tenant_id = account_default.tenant_id,
    ref_type         smallint               not null,
    ref_type_name    character varying(256),
    voucher_type     smallint               not null,
    column_name      character varying(64)  not null,
    column_caption   character varying(128) not null,
    filter_condition character varying(1024),
    default_value    character varying(32),
    sort_order       smallint,
    created          timestamp with time zone,
    created_by       character varying(64),
    modified         timestamp with time zone,
    modified_by      character varying(64),
    tenant_id        smallint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, tenant_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_tenant FOREIGN KEY (tenant_id) REFERENCES tenant (id)
);
```

Help me

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS account_default;
CREATE TABLE account_default
(
    id               smallint default value (max_value of account_default.id + 1 where tenant_id = account_default.tenant_id
```

I need composite key

```
(table_id, tenant_id)
(1, 1)
(2, 1)
(3, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 2)
(1, 3)
```

If insert, I need

```
(4, 1)
```

explain

```
4 = (max (table_id) where tenant_id = 1) + 1;
```

insert like tirgger or automation at database-side.

Comment: That is rather difficult to get and comes with a notable performance hit. Why not use a single-column, sequence-generated primary key?

Comment: If I use `serial` I need 4 byte, if I use `smallint` I need 2 byte. This is multi-tenant database.

Comment: You should use `bigint` and never mind the few GB wasted.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Base on your reputation rank, I think you have many experience in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

### [**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e9d646c1b6c79632fffb50a89a6d7177)

- changed all the *character varying* to text data type.
- changed small int to bigint data type.
- removed some not null constraint.
- the cost is figure out the new tenant id in the current table account_default or not.

---

function and trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION restart_seq ()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'new.tenant_id: %', NEW.tenant_id;
    RAISE NOTICE 'all.tenant_id: %', (
        SELECT
            array_agg(tenant_id)
        FROM
            tenant);
    RAISE NOTICE 'new.tenant_id in : %', (
        SELECT
            NEW.tenant_id IN (
                SELECT
                    tenant_id
                FROM
                    tenant));
    IF (NEW.tenant_id NOT IN (
        SELECT
            tenant_id
        FROM
            account_default)) THEN
        NEW.acc_id = 1;
        ALTER SEQUENCE account_default_acc_id_seq
            RESTART WITH 2;
        RAISE NOTICE 'currval(''account_default_acc_id_seq''): %', currval('account_default_acc_id_seq');
    END IF;
    RETURN new;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create or replace trigger  trg_reset_the_accid
    before insert on account_default
    for each  row execute  procedure restart_seq();
```